# libprotobuf.so.8 cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, protocol-buffers

I installed `caffe` on Ubuntu 16.04.

In the terminal I type into Python and `import caffe`, no error tips.

When I run a Python script use 'python demo.PY' I get one error with the following tip:

```
from ._caffe import Net SGDSolver...
```

> import error libprotobuf.so.8 cannot open shared object file.

I checked my ubuntu os and just found libprotobuf.so.9.

How do I fix this bug?

Comment: ...recompile the relevant Python module (ie. reinstalling it from its source package), or find an Ubuntu package with an old libprotobuf, presumably.

Comment: Determining *which* Python module is relevant, by the way, would require the full stack trace; since you've trimmed it, we can't be sure what it is from only what information is given here.